# "Pointer to pointer to int issue"

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind, free, gcc8

Today I tried to solve a Quiz from [Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-quiz-101-gq/) and when I reached the Question 3, there was the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    int *pInt;
    int **ppInt1;
    int **ppInt2;

    pInt = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    ppInt1 = (int**)malloc(10*sizeof(int*));
    ppInt2 = (int**)malloc(10*sizeof(int*));

    free( pInt );
    free( ppInt1 );
    free( *ppInt2 );
}
```

And the Question was:

> Choose the correct statement w.r.t. above C program:

```
A - malloc() for ppInt1 and ppInt2 isn’t correct. It’ll give compile time error.
B - free(*ppInt2) is not correct. It’ll give compile time error.
C - free(*ppInt2) is not correct. It’ll give run time error.
D - No issue with any of the malloc() and free() i.e. no compile/run time error
```

Because of this line:

```
free(*ppInt2);
```

Which for what I understand suggests that, there will be no compile or run time error, I decided that

```
free(*ppInt2)
```

is not correct.

But because there is no compile/run time errors here, makes Answers `B` and `C` wrong.

The Author says that the accepted Answer is:

```
D - No issue with any of the malloc() and free() i.e. no compile/run time error.
```

Now here is my Question, why is there no issue, because doing this:

```
free( *ppInt2 );
```

Valgrind reports:

```
==9468== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==9468== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==9468== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==9468== Command: ./program
==9468== 
==9468== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==9468==    at 0x4C30CF1: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9468==    by 0x1086C1: main (program.c:14)
==9468==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==9468==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9468==    by 0x108696: main (program.c:10)
==9468== 
==9468== 
==9468== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9468==     in use at exit: 80 bytes in 1 blocks
==9468==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 2 frees, 164 bytes allocated
==9468== 
==9468== 80 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==9468==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9468==    by 0x108696: main (program.c:10)
==9468== 
==9468== LEAK SUMMARY:
==9468==    definitely lost: 80 bytes in 1 blocks
==9468==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9468==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9468==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9468==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9468== 
==9468== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==9468== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I thought that the right `free` call should be:

```
free( ppInt2 );
```

Tested on `Linux mint 19`, `GCC-8` and `valgrind-3.13.0`

Comment: `free( *ppInt2 );` is undefined behavior, there is no concept of run time error in C standard. Your quizz cast return of `malloc` so I give them 0.

Comment: none of the options are correct statements

Comment: @SanderDeDycker That was my Point too.

Comment: @Michi : then your analysis is correct :)

Comment: There _could_ be a runtime error from `free(*ppInt2);` since that is one of the possible manifestations of undefined behaviour (specifically, "terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message)"). I expect that the quiz is looking for an answer of C. (Oh, except I see they claim D is correct. That's definitely wrong).

Comment: @Michi - to spare you another problem: The very next question uses an incorrect format specifier for printing a `sizeof` value. That makes all of *those* answers wrong. That site might not be the best place to learn C. :-)

Comment: Again and again "geeksforgeeks" proves to be a trash site, with amateurs writing articles and nobody proof-reading. Just don't use that site at all.

Comment: @BoPwrsson Thank you for your suggestion :)). I was not there to learn C, but to play some Quiz.

Comment: Get a better "quiz" site. Cast to/from `void *` are strongly discouraged. And none of the answer options is correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer C is closest to being correct.  The line

```
free( *ppInt2 );
```

is definitely incorrect.  The error is not one that can be detected by the compiler.  But it is quite likely to cause a run-time error.  (But it is not guaranteed to cause a run-time error.  More on this below.)

The rule for `malloc` and `free` is pretty simple: every pointer you hand to `free` must be exactly one that you received from a previous call to `malloc` (or `calloc`, or `realloc`).  In the code, the `malloc` and `free` calls for `pInt` and `ppInt1` correctly follow this rule.  But for `ppInt2`, the pointer returned by `malloc` is assigned to `ppInt2`, but the pointer handed to `free` is `*ppInt2`, the value pointed to by `ppInt2`.  But since `*ppInt2` -- that is, the value pointed to by `ppInt2` -- hasn't been initialized in any way, it's a garbage value, which `free` is likely to crash on.  The end result is more or less exactly as if you had said

```
int main()
{
    int *p;
    free(p);     /* WRONG */
}
```

But, again, a crash is not guaranteed.  So the more correct answer would therefore be worded as

> C' - `free(*ppInt2)` is not correct. It’ll likely give a run time error.

I'm afraid that someone who says that answer D is correct may not really know what they are talking about.  I would suggest not continuing further with this quiz -- who knows how many other wrong or misleading answers it contains?

It's always hard to understand undefined behavior, because undefined behavior means that *anything* can happen, including nothing.  When someone says "I heard that doing *X* was undefined, but I tried it, and it worked fine", it's just like saying "I heard that running across a busy street was dangerous, but I tried it, and it worked fine."

The other thing about undefined behavior is that *You have to think about it, and understand it, carefully*.  Pretty much by definition, no language translation tool -- no C compiler or other tool -- is guaranteed to warn you about it.  *You* have to know what's undefined, and what to therefore steer clear of.  You *can't* say "Well, my program compiles without errors or warnings, and it seems to work, so it must be correct."  In other words, you can't try to foist the "correct vs. incorrect" determination off onto the machine -- you have to own this distinction.

---

But perhaps you knew all that.  Perhaps the real question is simply, "If answer C is correct, how can the program *not* fail with a run-time error, in fact how can it repeatedly not fail?" This question has two answers:

1. As mentioned, undefined behavior means *anything* can happen, including nothing (i.e. no errors), including nothing on multiple successive runs.
2. On many systems, the first time `malloc` gives you a pointer to some brand-new memory, it's always all-bits-0 (that is, more or less as if you'd called `calloc`).  This is absolutely
   *not* guaranteed by the C Standards -- you should *never* depend on it -- but on those systems, it's so likely that it might as well be guaranteed.  Furthermore, on virtually all systems, a pointer value that's all-bits-0 is a null pointer.  So, and again only on those particular systems, and again only the first time `malloc` gives you a pointer to brand-new memory, the code `ppInt2 = malloc(10 * sizeof(int*))` will give you 10 null pointers. And since `free` is defined as doing nothing if you pass it a null pointer, in this specific case, `free(*ppInt2)` will never fail, not even at run time.  (Perhaps this is what the person setting the quiz had in mind, because *if* you make these additional assumptions, answer C as written is basically not correct, and answer D basically is -- I hate to admit this -- more or less accurate.)

Returning to an earlier analogy, if someone makes these additional assumptions, and notices that the code never fails, and tries to claim that answer D is correct instead, it's basically like saying, "I heard that running across the street was dangerous, but I tried it in the middle of the night, and it worked fine.  I even ran back and forth ten times.  I never got hit by a car, not even once".  And, unfortunately, there are programmers out there who follow similar logic, who will write programs that do the C programming equivalent of running across the street at all times. And these programmers then complain, as if it's not their fault, when inevitably their luck runs out and there's a horrible, fatal crash.

Comment: Well, imagine yourself how many people are making that Quiz :)).

Comment: `The error is not one that can be detected by the compiler` : Well, the funny thing by GCC is, that it takes its own decision when comes to something like that. Take a look [Here](https://pastebin.com/raw/72JmsALc), when you compile the same program with `-O3`. ==>> `total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 80 bytes allocated` instead of  ==>>> `total heap usage: 3 allocs, 2 frees, 164 bytes allocated`

Comment: for completeness : `free` can also be called for a null pointer without invoking undefined behavior. That's the principal reason that in many cases the shown code will not cause a runtime error (if `ppInt2` happens to point to zero initialized memory).

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Ah, right.  Good point.  (Which, returning to my analogy, is sort of like saying "I heard that running across a busy street was dangerous, but I tried it in the middle of the night, and it worked fine.  I even tried it ten times.")

Comment: @SanderDeDycker If you add some more information [Like Here](https://ideone.com/lomOlo) you will get those `free's` but still an [invalid free will take place](https://pastebin.com/raw/wDqTxEyG).

Comment: @SteveSummit : indeed - I wasn't trying to invalidate your answer. Just added the note to pre-empt the naysayers who live along a pedestrian-only street.

Comment: @Michi : that updated code has a double free (`free(ppInt2[0])` is the same as `free(*ppInt2)`) as well as a memory leak (`ppInt2` is never freed).

Comment: @DeDycker I no that. I only changed the free rules here :))

Comment: @Michi Perhaps you knew that answer C was or ought to be correct, and your question was simply, "Why does it never fail in practice, making it look like answer D is the right one instead?"  If so, I'm sorry for lecturing you on what you already knew, and I've added an additional few paragraphs at the end of this answer addressing that point.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker No worries, it's a fair point, and worth addressing in the answer.  (Well, no, not *really* a "fair" point, but seemingly fair for those parochial naysayers. :-) )

Answer (score 1):

Let's sort this out:

1. There is no compile time error here
2. There is no (ISO C standard specified) runtime error here, either, since there are next to none runtime errors in C. Essentially, the only runtime errors are errors (returned) from standard library functions.
3. The `free(*ppInt2)` is *undefined behaviour*. Anything can happen. Compiler may delete it, or it can even delete the whole `main()`, or much, much worse. If it just leaves it as-is, the `free()` function itself may also do anything - ignore, crash, report an error, mess up its bookkeeping by trying to free given pointer...
4. This is a *coding* error. Unfortunately, like many in C, it is not caught by the language compiler or it's runtime/standard library.

The fact that Valgrind catches this is nice selling point for the tool, but, it's not part of C language.

Comment: Actually, I'd say Valgrind is as much a part of the C language as gcc is.

Comment: @SteveSummit Well, in the sense that you _should_ use Valgrind, if you can, sure, you could (should? :) ) say that. But, it really isn't part of C (the language) and is available on only a handful of platforms - while C is available _everywhere_ and gcc is available for a _lot_ of platforms.